# Attempting to replace column values with a NaN by loc method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

Pandas help, please. I'm trying to replace the values in the "reading_score" column for Thomas High School students that are in the 9th grade. This syntax appears correct but it doesn't appear to be replacing any of the data.

Edit: I must've been tired because I see my syntax error. I'll leave this here, followed by the correction, in case others can use this as a teaching or learning tool.  Thanks for stopping by!

```py
student_data_df.loc[(["school_name"] == "Thomas High School") & (student_data_df["grade"] == "9th"), "reading_score"] = np.nan
student_data_df
```

```py
student_data_df.loc[(student_data_df["school_name"] == "Thomas High School") & (student_data_df["grade"] == "9th"), "reading_score"] = np.nan
student_data_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

(you are just missing student_data_df in student_data_df["school_name"])

```py
def set_reading_score_to_nan(df):
    df.loc[
        (df["school_name"] == "Thomas High School") & (df["grade"] == "9th"),
        "reading_score",
    ] = np.nan
    return df
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. How do I use this moving forward?  I am creating seccessive dataframes that can be individually referenced, correct?

Comment: I just added this to a function for the sake of testing it. But all you really need to do is add the data frame that you are indexing at the beginning for "school_name"